# Can't find variable error in react-native even if I am not using it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I am learning React-Native and I have created a Drawer which has already worked before. But after a few modifications not involving the Drawer it keeps giving this error `Can't find variable: Contact` even if I am not importing a variable called `Contact`.

**drawer.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { DrawerNavigator, DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation';
import ButtonScreen from '../screens/ButtonScreen';
import Contacts from '../screens/Contacts';
import Information from '../screens/Information';
import Preferences from '../screens/Preferences';

const Drawer = new DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: ButtonScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: 'Button'
        },
    },
    Contacts: {
        screen: Contacts,
    },
    Preferences: {
        screen: Preferences,
    },  
    Info: {
        screen: Information,
    }
}, {
    contentComponent: (props) => (
        <View>
            <Text>Custom Header</Text>
            <DrawerItems {...props}/>
            <Text>Custom Footer</Text>
       </View>
    )
});

export default Drawer;
```

**Contacts.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class Contacts extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
         super(props);
     }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>
                    Contact Component
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { isDrawerOpened } = state;
    return { isDrawerOpened };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Contacts);
```

By the stacktrace the error is comming from drawer.js line 6, where I import `Contacts` and not `Contact`. I already runned `npm start -- --reset-cache` to see if it would solve it but no. I am very confuse about why this is happening.

Comment: In Contact.js , what is Contact Componet ? inside render wrapped in Text Component

Comment: Line 6 would be import Information from '../screens/Information';
not the import to contact, what do you have inside screens/Information ?

Comment: Change your 

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      const { isDrawerOpened } = state;
      return { isDrawerOpened };
    }
to

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      isDrawerOpened: state.isDrawerOpened,
    }

Comment: Can you check the path of the contacts.

contacts and drawer files are in a different folder?

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace of the error you are getting?